# $(z_{2n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(z_{2n+1})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to same limit. Show $(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to the same limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

$(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a complex valued sequence such that subsequences $(z_{2n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(z_{2n+1})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to same limit.

How could I show that the sequence $(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to the same limit using $\epsilon$, $N$ definition?

---

For every $\epsilon >0$,

$|z_{2n}-l|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N_1$, and

$|z_{2n+1}-l|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N_2$.

We want to show that for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N$ such that $|z_{n}-l|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$.
I tried something like 
$|z_{n}-l|\le|z_n-z_{2n}|+|z_{2n}-l|$ but wasn't sure what to do next

Comment: Try rather $N=\max(2N_1+1,2N_2+2)$...

Comment: @Did Can you please elaborate a little more. I don't quite get it yet

Comment: Sure, could you please elaborate a little more on what you do not quite get yet?

Comment: @Did Ok. I got $|z_n-l|\le |z_n-z_{2n}|+|z_{2n}-l|$. If $n>N=max(2N_1+1,2N_2+2)$, then $n>N_2$, therefore $|z_{2n}-l|<\epsilon$. However I don't quite get how this can make $|z_n-z_{2n}|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Got something from my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Forget $|z_n-z_{2n}|$, which is a dead end (and a little absurd, if you ask me). Following my comment, let $N=\max(2N_1+1,2N_2+2)$ and $n\gt N$. Then:

- either $n$ is even, thus $n=2k$ with $k\gt N_1$ (because $N\geqslant2N_1+1$ and $n\gt N$) hence $|z_n-\ell|=|z_{2k}-\ell|\lt\epsilon$,
- or $n$ is odd, thus $n=2k+1$ with $k\gt N_2$ (because $N\geqslant2N_2+2$ and $n\gt N$) hence $|z_n-\ell|=|z_{2k+1}-\ell|\lt\epsilon$.

This proves that, for every $n\gt N$, $|z_n-\ell|\lt\epsilon$.